# If a class has no instance specific data is it okay to make it a singleton?

Tags: java, object-oriented-design, singleton

Let's say I have the following Java code:

```
public class ObjectConsumer implements Consumer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void accept(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Accepted " + o);
    }
}
```

Example singleton implementation:

```
public enum ObjectConsumer implements Consumer<Object> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void accept(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Accepted " + o)
    }
}
```

The class above has got no instance specific data (fields). Is it okay to make it a singleton? Is there anything I should keep an eye on when doing this or are there any clear drawbacks?

Comment: What do you mean "okay"? Why do you want to make it a singleton in the first place?

Comment: @JacquesB If there is no instance specific data then why would you need multiple instances?

Comment: @Mibac: If you only need one instance then just create one instance. If you don't have any instance specific data, I don't see why you would need to use a singleton pattern?

Comment: Design patterns don't exist to be used whenever you *can*, but to help you get it right when you *need* them.

Comment: I'm not sure how changing it from a class to an enum makes it a singleton.   Ever singleton I've used requires much more than than.  I would expect to at least see a static member and a getInstance() method.

Comment: This is not a class... it is a wrapper around a function.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Java doesn't have free functions

Comment: I am aware of this, which is why this was done this way. But, this makes the concept of a singleton invalid, conceptually, this is a function, how can it be a singleton?

Comment: @bluegreen using enums for singletons is advised in "Effective Java" as these cannot be instanciated twice. The getInstance()-way of doing things allows multiple copies to exist (for example by deserialization).

Comment: Why not make the method static? It seems to be appropriate here since it's a stateless function

Comment: @BlueWizard, That's interested, I've not run across that before.   I think I would have an objection to that approach because its not an enum, but I'm pretty pedantic like that.   As far as this question goes, I don't see any reason to make it a singleton either way.  I'm not a fan of using design patterns for the hell of it...there needs to be a reason to use them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not correct to make a class a Singleton, just because it has no instance data.

When a class is a Singleton, this gives a very specific message to the maintainers of the software:

> There must only ever be one instance of this class. Within the domain of the application, it does not make sense to have multiple instances of this class.

The simple fact that multiple instances would always behave identically, because they don't have instance data, or that you currently only need one instance (while having more is not a logical impossibility), is not enough of a reason to make the class a Singleton.

Comment: As an additional remark, a class with no instance specific data may be instantiated across multiple threads and destroyed after use. Converting it into a singleton would cause havoc, since thread B might try to use the singleton after thread A has used it.